# Flipping the first pixel in an image in asm

Tags: image, assembly, x86

Hi I am just doing this for practice before I create a loop that can flip an 3x3 image horizontally or vertically. I am using a variable called ap to store the addresses of the first pixel. I would also like to eventually use another variable called amp to store the mirrored pixel address, and also a register to store the calculated offset of the pixels but for now I put it in manually. No matter what I do the program doesn't swap them. Does anyone have an idea of what is the issue? Thank you for reading.

```
    mov ecx, dword ptr[eax + ecx * 4]
    mov ap, ecx   //temporary pixel address storage
    mov ecx, 0

    mov ecx, dword ptr[eax + ecx * 4 + 8]   //offset by 8 pixels
    mov [ap], ecx
```

Comment: I see you reading 2 consecutive dwords (assuming ecx is 0 on entry).  But it looks like you then try to write both to ap?  After you read the second dword, shouldn't you be writing it on top of the first dword?

Comment: The first AP is to hold the address of the first pixel and the second is an instruction to store the mirrored pixel into the address of AP.

Comment: As written, it doesn't appear that ecx contains an address at line 2.  Perhaps you meant `lea ecx, dword ptr[eax + ecx * 4]`?  Then the final mov statement will overwrite the first pixel.  Note that since you aren't saving the old value of the first pixel before you overwrite it, swapping will be hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using a variable called ap to store the addresses of the first pixel

If the *ap* variable is suppossed to contain an addresss than you need to use the `lea` instruction (not the `mov` instruction).

```
; For the 1st line EAX is address of image = address of 1st pixel
mov ecx, 0                          ;Index to 1st pixel
lea ecx, dword ptr[eax + ecx * 4]   ;Address of 1st pixel
mov [ap], ecx
mov ecx, 2                          ;Index to 3rd pixel
lea ecx, dword ptr[eax + ecx * 4]   ;Address of 3rd pixel
mov [amp], ecx
```

Now to swap these pixels and thus flipping the image you can write:

```
mov ecx, [ap]
mov edx, [amp]
mov [ap], edx
mov [amp], ecx
```

To proces the next lines of the image you could each time add the number of bytes per scanline to the `EAX` register. For an 3x3 image that's probably 12.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what this suppose to do:

```
 mov ecx, dword ptr[eax + ecx * 4]
```

whats in ecx? is it a counter for offset? but you are overriding it each time...
If you'r trying to save the original bit i think that you need to make sure you got the right value in ecx. try

```
mov ecx, 0
```

first (you can also `xor ecx, ecx` it gets the job done and its easier to read)